# Finding Data in SQL that fits a specific time period that is not concrete

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to write a query in SQL that will bring up data within a window of time. I need the End of Period (EP) to be between April 30, 2014 and March 31, 2016. However, I need to make sure there is 12 months of data prior to the anniversary. Here is what I have written so far:

```
Select
    acct_id, eom, acct_eff_dt, anniv_dt,
    mkt_sgmt, subacct,
    case 
       when eom < cast('2015-' || substr(anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || substr(a.anniv_dt,3,2) as date) 
          then 'yes' 
          else 'no' 
    end as before_anniv,
    cast('2015-' || substr(a.anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || substr(a.anniv_dt,3,2) as date)-365 as before_anniv_date,
    cast('2015-' || substr(a.anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || substr(a.anniv_dt,3,2) as date)+365 as after_anniv_date,
    sum(a.prem_rate_amt) as premium,
    sum(a.incurred_amt) as paid,
    (paid/premium) as lossratio
from 
    data
/*
inner join
    (select distinct
acct_id,
anniv_dt,
add_months(cast('2014-' || substr(anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || substr(anniv_dt,3,2) as date),-11)-1 as before_anniv,
add_months(cast('2014-' || substr(anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || substr(anniv_dt,3,2) as date),12)-1 as after_anniv

from data
where anniv_dt <> '    '
) b
on a.eom between before_anniv and after_anniv
*/


where 
    covrg_cd IN ('11','25','26')
    and mkt_sgmt in('NRMM','NRSG','LGC','LGL','MGC','MGL','TCF')
    and eom between '2014-05-31' and '2016-06-30'
    and prem_rate_amt <> '0'
group by 
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
order by 
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you add some sample data and why it should be returned or not?

Comment: don't you have to group by the first 9 fields?  and also field 12?

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier to debug and confirm your date is what you expect if you group in an outer query with an inner query like:

```
SELECT
    covrg_cd, mkt_sgmt, eom,  prem_rate_amt,
    acct_id, acct_eff_dt, anniv_dt,
    subacct,
    a.prem_rate_amt,
    a.incurred_amt,
    paid/premium AS lossratio,
    CAST('2015-' || SUBSTR(anniv_dt,1,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(a.anniv_dt,3,2)  AS DATE) AS dt_comp
FROM 
    DATA a
WHERE 
    covrg_cd IN ('11','25','26')
    AND mkt_sgmt IN('NRMM','NRSG','LGC','LGL','MGC','MGL','TCF')
    AND eom BETWEEN '2014-05-31' AND '2016-06-30'
    AND prem_rate_amt <> '0'
```

then in your outer query, you can refer to `dt_comp` directly instead of recalculating the same date 3 or more times.